# Unable to launch LXD VM

Tags: lxd

I'm trying to create a VM using LXD. The information on the server I am working on is as follows.

> os: Linux cpu01 5.4.0-165-generic #182-Ubuntu SMP Mon Oct 2 19:43:28 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
> CPU cores: 32
> lxd--version: 5.19

When I issue the lxd command as follows, the result is as follows.

> **user:~$ lxc launch ubuntu:20.04 testVm -c limits.cpu=64 --vm**
> Creating testVm
> Starting testVm
> Error: Failed to run: forklimits limit=memlock:unlimited:unlimited fd=3 fd=4 -- /snap/lxd/26093/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 -S -name testVm -uuid a26d8db4-1ee8-4616-822c-1080fc818bf4 -daemonize -cpu host -nographic -serial chardev:console -nodefaults -no-user-config -sandbox on,obsolete=deny,elevateprivileges=allow,spawn=allow,resourcecontrol=deny -readconfig /var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/logs/testVm/qemu.conf -spice unix=on,disable-ticketing=on,addr=/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/logs/testVm/qemu.spice -pidfile /var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/logs/testVm/qemu.pid -D /var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/logs/testVm/qemu.log -smbios type=2,manufacturer=Canonical Ltd.,product=LXD -runas lxd: : exit status 1
> Try `lxc info --show-log local:testVm` for more info

When the log is output, it says something like this.

> **user:~$ lxc info --show-log testVm**
>
> Log:
>
> qemu-system-x86_64: warning: Number of hotpluggable cpus requested
> (383) exceeds the recommended cpus supported by KVM (240) Number of
> hotpluggable cpus requested (383) exceeds the maximum cpus supported
> by KVM (288)

What should I do in these cases?